# I seem to 'break' my mysql client when I type in a Postgres command. Any ideas how to undo this?

Tags: mysql

Note: I'm using a bash shell on a nearly-fresh osx 10.6 install.  This doesn't seem to happen to a friend who is on zsh

I'm used to Postgres, so I often instinctually type

```
\d tablename
```

instead of

```
desc tablename ;
```

When I do this, the mysql client is not very happy

```
mysql> \d items
mysql> ;
    -> desc items;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
    ->
```

notice how my prompt changes after the 'oh crap' moment.  It seems to lock into this routine where all sql commands are considered to have invalid syntax.

i haven't figured out a sequence yet to escape this yet; nor have i figured out what is going on.

has anyone else encountered this, and knows how to get out of it ?  the only fix i've found is to ctrl-c and start a new mysql connection - and that's just not a proper fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL, `\d` changes the query delimiter, which is normally `;`. So you've actually changed your delimiter to `items`. For instance, try doing this:

```
\d items
desc items items
select 1 items
```

Fun times.

To change it back to semicolon, just do `\d ;`

Comment: ha! Thanks! This explains why I've been going batty.  I couldn't find anything in the man pages for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

`\d` changes the [statement delimiter.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html#id1909880)

You need to change it back to `;`

But you can't end a statement until you type `tablename`

so try typing `tablename` followed by `\d ;`

Personally `ctrl-c` `up-arrow` `enter` seems easier. Especially since mysql still remembers your command history between sessions.

Comment: ha! Thanks! This explains why I've been going batty.  I couldn't find anything in the man pages for whatever reason.